# New build using xCode 7 is not visible in the activity tab in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, build, xcode7, app-store-connect

I had uploaded a build using xcode 7 to iTunes Connect. It shows up in the activity tab for some time with status as processing. But if I refresh the browser window then the build disappears. I have uploaded many builds but for now use. I have waited for more than two days. But still the build is not visible in the activity tab. I have re-generated provisioning profile and then uploaded the build but still not visible. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I searched the web for this issue, some say that the build will start displaying after 24 hours some say there is problem with the provisioning profile. I waited for more then two days and changed my provisioning profile but for no use. Then I checked my email for any mail from Apple regarding the issue. I had mails from itunesconnect@apple.com specifying the issue with my code. It was as follows:

Dear developer,

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "XYZ". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

TestFlight SDK - TestFlight no longer requires an SDK to enable beta testing, crash reporting and analytics. To continue using TestFlight, set up Beta Testing in iTunes Connect and remove references to the SDK from the following executables: Fix It!.app/Fix It!

Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Regards,

The App Store team

I removed TestFlight SDK from my project and then again uploaded the app to iTunes Connect. It successfully uploaded and did not disappear again. I you are getting this issue I suggest you to check your Itunes Connect email to find for real issue.